# Single Serving Site

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I run a home server with MPD, CUPS, Deluge Seedbox with Web Client (for seeding linux to those who need it), Icecast, and FTP. One thing that's been bothering me when I connect to these services via my web browser, failure to specify the port number leads to a non-response. The solution I've dreamed up is to make a single serving webpage saying

`"averagejoey2000's headless server. 
Listen to Music http://example.com:8000
Print Server http://example.com:631
Deluge-Web http://example.com:8112
FTP http://example.com:21
admin mailto:averagejoey2000@example.com"`

I've heard that apache and nginx are huge undertakings, suitable for up to 10,000 concurrent connections. I don't need any of that, I can count the number of users on 1 hand.
Is there a daemon which will serve 1 webpage to example.com:80 with minimal effort?

Comment: apache (and probably nginx) are actually pretty simple to implement if you just want to serve a single static page inside a LANs firewall. in fact you already have a webserver running for your other sites anyway. you could probably just edit the default landing page. do you have anything listening on port 80 `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 is the tricky bit here. Apache and ngnix arn't *that* hard, but lighttpd seems more what you're looking for. It *will* handle a large number of connections, but Its really designed more for ease of use and configuration more than anything else.

just stick your file in /var/www/index.html and delete the default index page

Literally no configuration needed here

That said, if you've got the ability to do nameserver records, this also has a basic reverse proxy option so you can name these things like music.example.com and so on.

If port 80's not what you *really* want to use you can just make a new directory, stick your index file there and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

I use this to expose a directory of arbitrary readonly files secureishly to my web server for sheer laziness.

Comment: Don't have access to the nameserver. I am not my network administrator, I only run the server. Will definitely use lighttpd. Thanks Mr!

Answer (score 0):

One more solution since I think  `lighttpd` is "too heavy" just to serve static html.
[busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) would be much lighter

```
#!/bin/sh

ListeningPort=80
DocumentRoot='/path/to/html'

# gist
busybox httpd -p ${ListeningPort} -h "${DocumentRoot}"
```